# Next.JS fetch and Axios request timing out on Vercel production

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, fetch-api, vercel

I'm trying to fetch a specific JSON data, but it times out and never gets the response back and ends up timing out on Vercel deploy. The response I'm fetching is only 18KB and the fetch request works fine in dev on localhost. However when I deploy it to Vercel, it simply doesn't fetch anymore. I've tried using axios, but same issue occurs.
This is the JSON data I'm trying to fetch:

https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/documents/json/ee_rounds_123_en.json

Here's my code inside the api routes folder:

**/api/checkUpdates.tsx**

```
const url = 'https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/documents/json/ee_rounds_123_en.json'
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {

    console.log('before fetch request')
    console.time('fetch')
    
    const data = await fetch(url)
    
    // from here on, it only executes on localhost
    console.timeEnd('fetch')
    console.log('fetch success')

    const json = await data.json();
    console.log('success')
    const thisDraw = json.rounds[0]
    res.send(thisDraw?.drawNumber)
}
```

When I try to fetch the page https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/documents/json/ee_rounds_123_en.json from a Vercel deploy it takes forever and never loads. Same thing happens if I try using axios. It works normally on localhost, though.
Apparently it's something related to that page specifically, as I've tried fetching other JSONs from the web and it worked fine.

Next.JS v13.2.3

Comment: Could you share those `console logs` or your `vercel log drains` with us

Comment: It only logs 'before fetch request' on Vercel, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think the server version of node is 16 or below so you would need to install [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)
- Or change vercel node version to 18

```
yarn add node-fetch
```

or

```
npm install node-fetch
```

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const data = await fetch(url)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the issue. Now I'm curious. Vercel says it's using Node version 18 on production... So am I on my localhost environment. Why does normal fetch or axios work on localhost and not on Vercel? node-fetch worked fine on Vercel

Comment: Your version is 18 it has native support for `fetch()`. on Vercel the default version is 16 but you can change it to 18.